# Use regex to match a series of numbers 1-9, with no repetition

Tags: c#, regex

I need to be able to match a series of numbers, (any number between `1` and `9`), with as many different digits as the user enters but no repetition.

> 123456789 -> match
>   1223 -> no match

In effect, the number must be between 1 and 9 digits long, containing only numbers, and not repeat any digit.

**How would I do this using regex?**

Comment: Are the numbers necessarily ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
(?!.*([1-9]).*\1)^[1-9]{1,9}$
```

`(?!.*([1-9]).*\1)` - negative look ahead checking if the digits don't repeat.

Sample matches:  http://regexr.com?2trr6

Comment: I can't get that to match of my of my sample numbers: `12351874`. Can you? EDIT: unless they don't want the number previously used to appear anywhere within the string...

Comment: That shouldn't match -- the digit "1" is repeated.  This solution correctly says this doesn't match.

Comment: @Brad Christie - sorry, not really understanding your question here

Comment: +1 - You beat me to it.  (This problem is a lot harder than it seems.)  I knew look ahead / behind was the key, but didn't make the leap that you could lookahead the whole thing like that.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

I honestly use more php than c#, but this should work

```
^(?:([1-9])(?![1-9]*?\1))*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:([1-9])(?!\1))+$
```

That is, a digit, followed by something which isn't the same digit, at least one time.

Sorry, misinterpreted question. I thought you meant it should fail if the same number is used twice in a row. If you want no repetitions for the *whole* sequence of digits, use:

```
^(?:([1-9])(?!.*\1))+$
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear but I expect that each digit is only allowed once, e.g. '123123' would not be a match.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted it. I thought you meant only if the digit was twice in a row (like 1221). I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **different** solution. This is how I would have done. I'm not a big fan of lookaheads/lookbehinds unless they make really easier the code.

```
string numbers = "123456789";
string example = "12345 1123456 19283741 987654321";

var matches = Regex.Matches(example, @"\d+");
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++) {
    var match = matches[i].Value;
    if (!numbers.Any(number => match.Count(x => x == number) >= 2)) {
        Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
}
```

If you run it, you'll see it prints:

```
12345
987654321
```

I think it is pretty straightforward what I'm doing here.

I'm extracting all the numbers from the text, no matter if it has repeated digits or not, and then, for each number (`1 - 9`), it will take only those matches that do not contain more than one repetition.